# Google closure compiler is replacing the jQuery word 'special'

Tags: jquery, google-closure-compiler

I'm using Google's closure compiler (with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS) and when I run the minified version of my site I get this error in Firebug...

```
TypeError: a.event.Yd is undefined
```

This is coming from `jquery.mousewheel.js`

It looks like this line...

```
$.event.special.mousewheel = {
```

Is getting converted into ...

```
a.event.Yd.Tc = {
```

Can someone confirm that it shouldn't be doing this?

I am using the jQuery externs file so I though a jQuery plugin would be safe. Does it look like there is something wrong with the jQuery externs file to have allowed `special` to be replaced? Any idea how to fix this?

(Alternatively, as jquery.mousewheel.js also comes in a minified version so  there is the option of not putting it through the Google Closure. But then as i understand it I would need to figure out how to create an externs file for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery exters file seems to be missing the 'special' property

Adding this to the externs file fixes it...

`jQuery.event.special = function(arg1) {};`